# Why does the Bhagavata Purana say Vyasa incarnated before Rama?

Tags: rama, avatars, bhagavata-purana, vyasa

Bhagavatam describes supreme personality of godhead incarnated as Vyasa before Rama:

[SB 1.3.21](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/21)

> Thereafter, **in the seventeenth incarnation of Godhead**, Śrī Vyāsadeva appeared in the womb of Satyavatī through Parāśara Muni, and he divided the one Veda into several branches and subbranches, seeing that the people in general were less intelligent.

[SB 1.3.22](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/22)

> **In the eighteenth incarnation, the Lord appeared as King Rāma**. In order to perform some pleasing work for the demigods, He exhibited superhuman powers by controlling the Indian Ocean and then killing the atheist King Rāvaṇa, who was on the other side of the sea.

Why does the Bhagavata Purana say so?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Lord's incarnations are not given in chronological order, these are some other references from the same source which you have used in your question:

**10th incarnation:** [SB 1.3.15](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/15)

> When there was a complete inundation after the period of the Cākṣuṣa Manu (6th Manu) and the whole world was deep within water, the Lord accepted the form of a fish (**Matsya Avtar**) and protected Vaivasvata Manu (7th Manu), keeping him up on a boat.

**11th incarnation:** [SB 1.3.16](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/16)

> The eleventh incarnation of the Lord took the form of a tortoise whose shell served as a pivot for the Mandarācala Hill, which was being used as a churning rod by the theists and atheists of the universe.

However, there are more than one reference found for Matsya incarnation (earlier, it happened to save Vedas as well) but here the shloka clearly tells about Matsya incarnation which happened at the end of previous Manvantar and at the beginning of current Manvantar.

Kurma (Tortoise) and Dhanvantari incarnations happened during Samundra manthan. And all the sources say that Samundra manthan happened in the 6th Manavantar.

But, here Matsya incarnation is depicted as 10th and Kurma as 11th which shows that **strict** chronological order is not followed.

In your question, Vedvyasa is clearly mentioned as son of Satyvati and Parasar. So, there is no possibility that it is referring some other Vyasa other than  28th Dwapar yuga's Vyasa. However there may be chances that it is referring Vyasa of some other Kalpa/Manvantara altogether. List of all the Vedvyasas of current Manvantar can be found in [Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp077.htm).

[Vayu Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vayu_purana/incarnations_of_vishnu%20.html) mention that Rama incarnated before Vyasa.
[image]

Comment: Hi YDS, You gave a wonderful detailed answer. 
I have two questions: You mention that Samudra manthan happened in 6th Manvantar. Where is the evidence for the same? I have been looking for it.

Comment: @sidharthchhabra "Samudra manthan happened in 6th Manvantar" can be concluded from SB 8.5

Answer (score 2):

Garuda Purana Skanda 1, Chapter 1, sloka 29 states:

> ततः सप्तदशे जातः सत्यवत्यां पराशरात् ।
>    चक्रे वेदतरोः शाखां
> दृष्ट्वा पुंसोऽल्पमेधसः
> In the 17Th incarnation god came as the son of Sathyavati and Prashara
> seeing men defecient in knowledge he branched the tree of veda.

And, Srimad Bhagavatam Skanda 1, Chapter 3, Sloka 21 states:

> ततः सप्तदशे जातः सत्यवत्यां पराशरात् ।
>  चक्रे वेदतरोः शाखां
> दृष्ट्वा पुंसोऽल्पमेधसः
>
> Thereafter, in the seventeenth incarnation of Godhead, Śrī Vyāsadeva
> appeared in the womb of Satyavatī through Parāśara Muni, and he
> divided the one Veda into several branches and subbranches, seeing
> that the people in general were less intelligent.

both of them are exactly the same sloka.

Comment: I have edited the answer. When you quote someone else's texts, then you have to put them in the blockquote as I have done. BTW welcome to site! keep posting.

Comment: @Rickross thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

SB 1.3.22 does not mention the name of Rama or the killing of Ravana at all and so the above translation seems incorrect.

> nara-devatvam āpannaḥ sura-kārya-cikīrṣayā
>
> samudra-nigrahādīnicakre vīryāṇy ataḥ param
>
> Synonyms:
> nara — human being; devatvam — divinity; āpannaḥ — having assumed the form of; sura — the gods; kārya — activities; cikīrṣayā — for the purpose of performing; samudra — the sea; nigraha-ādīni — controlling etc, ; cakre — did perform; vīryāṇi — superhuman prowess; ataḥ param — thereafter

Ref: the link of the sloka provided in the question. I have just changed demi-gods to gods and indian ocean to sea. Sagar does not mean the Indian Ocean and there is no word in our ancient culture as demigod.

The actual translation therefore should be something like this : Then, assuming a divine human form, the Lord appeared for helping the gods and controlling the sea by His superhuman power.

So there is NO mention of the killing of Ravana. Just helping the gods and contolling the sea etc does not repesent Sri Rama.

Moreover, according to the Gaudiya explanation of Bhagavatam, the avatara of treta yuga is red-coloured. They had to make this to make the avatar of kali yellow-coloured, ie Sri Chaitanyadeva. In satya yuga, the avatar was white-complexioned and in black in dwapara. It is true that these four colours have been mentioned in the bhagavata.

Garga Muni confirmed in Srimad Bhagavatam that although the child Krishna was black, He also appears in three other colors -- red, white and yellow. He exhibited His white and red complexions in the Satya and Treta ages respectively.and as per yellow that was used in kali yuga as Chaitanya mahaprabhu.

So the texts of Bhagavata along with the Gaudiya and BBT interpretations make it very confusing. If we accept that Vyasdeva was born before Rama, then we have also to accept that Rama's skin colour was red!

Comment: Then kindly do post the correct translation for that verse. On the side, a verse need not mention exact names and it can be inferred who it is refering to.

Comment: @Ambi yes I have added

Comment: sorry, but what makes your version the actual translation? That is why the rules here are for citing a proper reference.

Comment: I have read the original sanskrit verse and translated it word by word. You are free to check it yourself.

Comment: Thats not how it works here. (I can translate many verses literally and post it here and the entire place will be on fire, figuratively). But, Everyone is being held to the same standard. I am just telling you what that standard is. Posting the references will ensure your answer isn't flagged for lack of citation.

Comment: The link to the original verse is there in the question. There are meanings of each word also given there. While giving translation of the entire sloka, many things have been added.

Comment: Partha ji, I have tried to explain to you what the rule is. Rules are for everybody. Can't say I didn't try.

Comment: Okay thnx i have given the ref

Comment: Hello! Please use block quotes when you are copying something from references.

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee You just copy pasted from the question! Well, here's an actual reference... https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n31. It is not by any Gaudiya Vaishnava or ISKCON author, since you are so particular to pull them in to everything. It is from "well respected publisher" and even they clearly mention Ravana, which means the Lord referred to is Sri Rama. So how does your translation stand accurate now? Will you now claim that Motilal Banarsidass translations are also confusing?

Comment: Do you know sanskrit? If yes, you could read the sloka yourself.

Comment: How accepting Ram's colour as red is going to answer question?

Comment: then you become sure that the 18th avatara is Rama

Comment: But how does it answer why was Vyasa mentioned before Rama? Vyasa appeared in last DWapara yuga and he should be counted later than Rama who appeared in Treta yuga.

Comment: Thats what I meant. There is nothing in SB 1.3.22 that clearly indicates Sri Rama.

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee then who is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88575/discussion-between-partha-banerjee-and-rare).

Comment: If that doesn't represent Rama, then it appears that Suta Goswami forgot to mention such an important incarnation Rama from the list, strange, is it not?

Comment: Yes, of course. There are so many mysteries. Why do so many events differ from Mahabharat for example?